# How to bring multiple column values from multiple rows (notConcatenate)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables as below.

Table **Person**

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |

Table **PersonStatus**

| PersonID | Status | DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Arrived | 2022-02-01 06:00:00 |
| 1 | Called | 2022-02-01 07:00:00 |
| 1 | Seen | 2022-02-01 07:45:00 |

I want to write a query which should produce results like below - i.e. only one record for a person:

| PersonID | ArrivedDateTime | CalledDateTime | SeenDateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-02-01 06:00:00 | 2022-02-01 07:00:00 | 2022-02-01 07:45:00 |

I have tried various 'concatenation' methods like CTE, Stuff (XML) etc. but I again need to split these strings into columns, which I don't want.

Is there any way I can achieve the above?
(As per requirement, this should be a single query, with no provision for temp tables, cursors etc.)

I know we can LEFT JOIN PersonStatus multiple times, for each status, but that will hit performance.

**UPDATE**

I have taken hint from below link, using aggregate functions
[Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

```
SELECT b.* FROM Person A
left join 
(
select PersonID, 
  max(case when Status = 'Arrived' then DateTime end) ArrivedDTTM,
  max(case when Status = 'Called' then DateTime end) CalledDTTM,
  max(case when Status = 'Seen' then DateTime end) SeenDTTM
from PersonStatus 
group by PersonID
) B on A.ID = B.PersonID
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show what you tried